# Ussing error prompts in asp/mvc application

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I ve  been looking for a straight forward way to prompt error messages, ideally a popup, (javascript or otherwise) to users failing the login system on this form:

```
@model Blog.Models.ViewModels.LoginView
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<p>Your name: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.name) </p>
<p>Your password: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.password)</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />    
}
</body>
</html>
```

but most examples I ve found use the onclick method on a label. Instead i want it to be handled by this controller:

```
private BlogModel model = new BlogModel();
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoginForm(string name, string password)
    {
                SysUser user = model.SysUsers.Where(x => x.SysUserName == name).First();
                {
                    if (user != null && user.SysPassword == password)
                    {
                        Session["usrn"] = name;
                        return RedirectToAction("LoginSuccessful", "Users");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //display error//
                    }
                }
```

Comment: use `Ajax.BeginForm()` instead of `Html.BeginForm()`

Comment: Add a bit of script to the page in TempData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend against a popup or alert() dialog. Instead, I would use a styled div to display your error messages. If you're using jQuery UI, you could try my [message plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-message/). Since its displayed with javascript, you can use it like so:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoginForm(string name, string password)
{
    SysUser user = model.SysUsers.Where(x => x.SysUserName == name).First();
    {
        if (user != null && user.SysPassword == password)
        {
            Session["usrn"] = name;
            return RedirectToAction("LoginSuccessful", "Users");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.LoginError = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Markup with jquery-message:

```
<div id="loginError" style="display:none">Login Error...</div>

@if (ViewBag.LoginError == true)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#loginError").message({type:"error"});
    </script>
}
```

Or if you prefer, without jquery-message:

```
@if (ViewBag.LoginError == true)
{
    <div id="loginError" class="error">Login Error...</div>
}
```

Comment: Yep, thanks jrummell thats pretty much what I needed. I just had to add a new action on the controler in which to define LoginError like so:
`public ActionResult LoginFailed()
        {
            ViewBag.LoginError = true;
            return View("LoginForm");
        }`
And then redirect to that otherwise LoginForm action wouldnt have an output but now it works!